# Degeneracy in singular homology

Tags: reference-request, homology-cohomology

I Would like to know a place (book, paper) that discuss thorougly the problem of degenerate elements in singular homology.
I know that they are not a problem with simplices but you need to explicity deal with them in cubic homology (Massey for instance)
I have read an terse old paper by Tucker (degenerate cycles bound) that address the problem in simplicial homology but I would like further details.
In fact I am puzzled because all the standard texts tiptoe this matter (Hatcher, Munkres, Rotman, Vick).
Thank you very much.
To further clarify
Is there any result that allows to forget degeneracy at once or should we check that is not a problem in any theorem (Hurewicz for instance

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: One reason that you don't see any particular discussions of degenerate simplices in singular homology is that they cause absolutely no problems. Why make a big deal out of something that causes no problems?

Comment: Nonetheless, if you want to see a theory in which degenerate simplices ***do*** play a special role, you might enjoy reading about [simplicial sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplicial_set).

Comment: If you can prove the Hurewicz theorem without explicitly mentioning degeneracy, then doesn't that demonstrate that it's not a problem? As @MoisheKohan asked, what exactly is the problem? Perhaps you might start by defining what you mean by "degenerate" in this context.

Comment: Yes  an other demo is that you get Eilemberg Stenrod axioms with degenerate simplices by the way by degenerste I mean that the singular simlplex application does not depend of one or more barycentric coordinate of the standsr simplex. But when I read Massey and saw that you need to take into account degenerate quadrilaterals I stsrt to be interested in more details on degenerate simplices. Most at the intuitive level

Comment: Thank you Lee Mosher. I have found some lecture notes on simplicial sets mainly for homotopy or higher order categories. Do you know any good reference for that. Thank you very much

Comment: Moishe Kohan Let us suppose that someone starts with the Massey book that use cubic homology and from the very begining has to deal with everything module degenerate quadrilaterals. Later he reads Rotman  or Vick and hardly find a word about degenerate simplices would not he thought that he was missing someyhing trivial that make degenerate simplices harmless. That is my problem I know that degenerate simplices are harmless but I dont have the geometric intuition of the reason for that. I am not sure if this is really a question if not I apologize. In any case Thank you very much.